# How to get a URL from .route in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, redirect, routes, response

I have a Flask app that routes the user to the report page based on the object that has been passed in @.route():

```
@mod.route('/page/<object>')
def page(object):
   #some manipulations based on object
   return redirect(url_for("another_page.index"))
```

It works just fine with Domain names, emails, or any other type of object, but fails with 404 if the object is an URL, basically if it starts with 'http://'.

Question: How can I pass URL in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple solution. All I had to do is to add a converter '**path:**' for an object:

```
@mod.route('/page/<path:object>')
def page(object):
  #some manipulations based on object
  return redirect(url_for("another_page.index"))
```

[Flask Route Documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/?highlight=route#url-route-registrations)